# tf api usage : stop_if_no_decrease_hook

Tags: tensorflow

I wanna use stop_if_no_decrease_hook tf api in object detection.

But I can't stop training process.

```
early_stopping = tf.contrib.estimator.stop_if_no_decrease_hook(
    estimator,
    metric_name='loss',
    max_steps_without_decrease=5,
    min_steps=0
)

early_stopping2 = tf.contrib.estimator.stop_if_lower_hook(
    estimator,
    metric_name='total_loss',
    threshold=10,
    eval_dir=None,
    min_steps=0,
    run_every_secs=60,
    run_every_steps=None
)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=train_steps, hooks=[early_stopping, early_stopping2])
```

I don't know what is the right metric_name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import logging
from tensorflow.python.training import session_run_hook

class EarlyStoppingHook(session_run_hook.SessionRunHook):
"""Hook that requests stop at a specified step."""

  def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=0,
             mode='auto'):

    self.monitor = monitor
    self.patience = patience
    self.min_delta = min_delta
    self.wait = 0
    if mode not in ['auto', 'min', 'max']:
        logging.warning('EarlyStopping mode %s is unknown, '
                        'fallback to auto mode.', mode, RuntimeWarning)
        mode = 'auto'

    if mode == 'min':
        self.monitor_op = np.less
    elif mode == 'max':
        self.monitor_op = np.greater
    else:
        if 'acc' in self.monitor:
            self.monitor_op = np.greater
        else:
            self.monitor_op = np.less

    if self.monitor_op == np.greater:
        self.min_delta *= 1
    else:
        self.min_delta *= -1

    self.best = np.Inf if self.monitor_op == np.less else -np.Inf

def begin(self):
    # Convert names to tensors if given
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    self.monitor = graph.as_graph_element(self.monitor)
    if isinstance(self.monitor, tf.Operation):
        self.monitor = self.monitor.outputs[0]

def before_run(self, run_context):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
    return session_run_hook.SessionRunArgs(self.monitor)

def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
    current = run_values.results

    if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
        self.best = current
        self.wait = 0
    else:
        self.wait += 1
        if self.wait >= self.patience:
            run_context.request_stop()
```